# Help with filter logic

Tags: filters

I'm trying to set up filter criteria which works, unlike what I have below.

```
(1 AND 2) OR (8 AND 9) OR 
(1 AND 3) AND 4)) NOT (8 AND 9) OR 
(1 AND 5) NOT (8 AND 9) OR 
(1 AND 6) NOT (8 AND 9) OR 
(7 AND 6) NOT (8 AND 9) OR 
(7 AND 2) NOT (8 AND 9)
```

Essentially, I want the filer logic to alert when `1 AND 2` match, only if `8 AND 9` do not match. So it's ok if `1 AND 2` match, as long as `8 AND 9` do not match. This same logic applies to `1 AND 3 AND 4`, `1 AND 5`, `1 AND 6`, `7 AND 6`, `7 AND 2`.

Hoping someone can help!

Answer (score 5):

Boy, your AND's are confusing, nevertheless if by **match** you mean their result is true then you should try something like this -

> Essentially, I want the filer logic to alert when 1 AND 2 match, only
>   if 8 AND 9 do not match

( (1 AND 2) AND NOT (8 AND 9) )

This is only for the first case, I am hoping you can do the same for the rest.

Comment: As a bit of a hint for OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question), if a common thing appears in all of your terms (e.g. in `(1 OR 2) AND (1 OR 3) AND (1 OR 4)`, the `1` is common to all the terms), you can simplify things by pulling the common part out so that it only appears once (e.g. `1 OR (2 AND 3 AND 4)` in this case). Knowing a bit of Boolean Algebra (mostly DeMorgan's Law, Law of Distributivity of and/or over or/and, and Absorption Law) really helps.